# Does a Rotational Field QMR-Cytotron cure arthritis?

Tags: medical-science

My father-in-law is diagnosed with Osteo-arthritis. As per doctors' advice, we are now planning for his knee replacement surgery.

Today, I came to hear about a procedure that claims to use a [Quantum Magnetic Resonance Cytotron](http://www.cytotrontreatment.com/)  to regenerate cells. The procedure is co-developed by The Institute of Aerospace Medicine (IAM) of the Indian Air Force and the Bangalore-based Centre for Advanced Research and Development (CARD)  some years ago. [(news report)](http://www.hindu.com/2005/07/12/stories/2005071214360200.htm)

These seems to be no real medical references to this treatment of procedure. Google results some links to [inventors links](http://www.safehealth.in/).

Does this really work?

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteoarthritis) looks like advertisement than article.

> Treatment of Osteoarthritis And Other Types of Cartilage Damage When
>   cartilage erosion exceeds the rate at which it is produced it
>   eventually results in osteoarthritis. Almost 1 out of every 20
>   Europeans suffer from a form of osteoarthritis. In general, it is
>   assumed that osteoarthritis is an irreversible process. Until now, the
>   medical treatment only dealt with the symptoms of osteoarthritis (pain
>   and stiffness) through pain medication, physiotherapy or injections
>   into the painful joint and could not offer a cure. Continued wear,
>   aside from pain and stiffness may also cause deformities inside and
>   outside of the joint. For advanced osteoarthritis, usually the only
>   solution is joint replacement surgery. In most cases, when a joint has
>   been affected by osteoarthritis, the sufferer will try to spare the
>   affected joint by shifting the weight away from the painful joint, and
>   this can cause the osteoarthritis to spread to other joints.
>
> With the introduction of the CytotronTM it is possible to treat the
>   osteoarthritis itself by stimulating the production of cartilage by
>   means of RFQMR. In principle, other forms of cartilage damage (such as
>   sports injuries) are also treatable. The treatment is painless.
>   Depending on the size and type of the joint it may take 30 to 60
>   minutes a day. The treatments must take place on 21 consecutive days
>   (including the weekend!).

Comment: Please be aware that we can examine and answer the claims in your question, we are legally not in a position to provide medical advice. That said, all current claims of quantum mechanics healing are pseudoscience. The institute behind CytotronTM is furthermore known for providing other quack treatments such as [chelation therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelation_therapy). Summary: this is almost certainly a scam.

Comment: @KonradRudolph chelation therapy is a completely legitimate treatment for lead poisoning.  "chelation therapy is considered a mainstay
in the medical management of children with BLLs >
45μg/dL" http://www.cdc.gov/nceh/lead/publications/refugeetoolkit/pdfs/medicaltechnicalbrief.pdf  Of course it is always possible to abuse a legitimate treatment by using it when there is no need for it.

Comment: @DavePhD You're absolutely correct of course.